# Postgresql : ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to load a .sql dump file using pgAdmin. However getting the following error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 2757: \.
           ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 68298
```

It looks like this in code :

[image]

Even if I delete it, it gets the same error in next `\.`

If I delete all, gives another error.

Comment: Maybe the error is at the end of the previus line

Comment: Do not use images to post textual information. In this case the image cuts off  important information. Replace the image with a properly formatted copy and paste of the lines in question. At a guess the  pgAdmin QueyEditor can't handle the '\'.

Comment: pgAdmin doesn't support `copy ... from stdin` you need to use `psql` to run that script

Comment: You might want to try https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/restore_dialog.html or https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/import_export_data.html

Comment: as we're forced to guess possibly a missing semicolon on line 2756